# Getting Error while adding Email composer plugin in phonegap "Error adding plugin com.example.abc"

Tags: cordova

I am using **Email Composer** in my app .I download plugin from Internet for Android .
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/EmailComposerWithAttachments.
And after that i do that same thing which is written in the Readme File.

Add java file in my src code.
add js file in my js folder.
Add plugin in `config.xml` file.

```
<plugin name="EmailComposer" value="com.example.procat"/>
```

But still i am getting this error.

```
***06-30 11:23:47.507: D/CordovaLog(660): ****************************AVVIATO
06-30 11:23:47.507: I/Web Console(660): ****************************AVVIATO at file:///android_asset/www/js/EmailComposer.js:20
06-30 11:23:47.507: W/System.err(660): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.procat
06-30 11:23:47.517: W/System.err(660):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-30 11:23:47.517: W/System.err(660):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:227)
06-30 11:23:47.517: W/System.err(660):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:174)
06-30 11:23:47.517: W/System.err(660):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginEntry.getClassByName(PluginEntry.java:102)
06-30 11:23:47.517: W/System.err(660):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginEntry.createPlugin(PluginEntry.java:78)
06-30 11:23:47.517: W/System.err(660):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:258)
06-30 11:23:47.517: W/System.err(660):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:215)
06-30 11:23:47.527: W/System.err(660):  at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:51)
06-30 11:23:47.527: W/System.err(660):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:221)
06-30 11:23:47.527: W/System.err(660):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:581)
06-30 11:23:47.527: W/System.err(660):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 11:23:47.537: W/System.err(660):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-30 11:23:47.537: W/System.err(660):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
06-30 11:23:47.537: W/System.err(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 11:23:47.537: W/System.err(660):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-30 11:23:47.537: W/System.err(660):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-30 11:23:47.537: W/System.err(660):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-30 11:23:47.537: W/System.err(660):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 11:23:47.547: W/System.err(660): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.procat
06-30 11:23:47.547: W/System.err(660):  ... 18 more
06-30 11:23:47.557: W/System.err(660): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.procat in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.procat-1.apk]
06-30 11:23:47.557: W/System.err(660):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
06-30 11:23:47.568: W/System.err(660):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
06-30 11:23:47.568: W/System.err(660):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
06-30 11:23:47.568: W/System.err(660):  ... 18 more
06-30 11:23:47.568: I/System.out(660): Error adding plugin com.example.procat.
06-30 11:23:47.568: D/PluginManager(660): exec() call to unknown plugin: EmailComposer***
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin needs updating for more recent versions of Cordova. You can download my Eclipse test project containing the updated plugin code and the resulting APK [from here](http://ge.tt/9V4dBck/v/0).

Note that because of this [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38303) in Android 4.x I had to replace this line in EmailComposer.java:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
```

with

```
ArrayList<String> extra_text = new ArrayList<String>();
extra_text.add(body);
emailIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extra_text);
```

This works around the problem for plain text emails but won't work for HTML emails because Spanned (returned by Html.fromHtml) is not a subclass of Charsequence. When I tried casting the result of Html.fromHtml() to a string, the tags appeared as part of the text :-(

Also when I tried this, the body of plain text emails to appeared when using the Gmail app but it didn't appear in stock Email app - body was always blank.

Code for the updated plugin:

**EmailComposer.java**

```
/**
 *
 * Phonegap Email composer plugin for Android with multiple attachments handling
 *
 * Version 1.0
 *
 * Guido Sabatini 2012
 *
 */

package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.Html;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.LOG;

public class EmailComposer extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if ("showEmailComposer".equals(action)) {

            try {
                JSONObject parameters = args.getJSONObject(0);
                if (parameters != null) {
                    sendEmail(parameters);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            callbackContext.success();
            return true;
        }
        return false;  // Returning false results in a "MethodNotFound" error.
    }

    private void sendEmail(JSONObject parameters) {

        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

        //String callback = parameters.getString("callback");

        boolean isHTML = false;
        try {
            isHTML = parameters.getBoolean("bIsHTML");          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling isHTML param: " + e.toString());
        }

        if (isHTML) {
            emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        } else {
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        }

        // setting subject
        try {
            String subject = parameters.getString("subject");
            if (subject != null && subject.length() > 0) {
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling subject param: " + e.toString());
        }

        // setting body
        try {
            String body = parameters.getString("body");
            if (body != null && body.length() > 0) {
                if (isHTML) {                                       
                    String bodyHtml = Html.fromHtml(body).toString();
                    LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Creating HTML email with body: " + bodyHtml);
                    ArrayList<String> extra_text = new ArrayList<String>();
                    extra_text.add(bodyHtml);
                    emailIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extra_text);
                } else {
                    LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Creating text email with body: " + body);
                    ArrayList<String> extra_text = new ArrayList<String>();
                    extra_text.add(body);
                    emailIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extra_text);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling body param: " + e.toString());
        }

        // setting TO recipients
        try {
            JSONArray toRecipients = parameters.getJSONArray("toRecipients");
            if (toRecipients != null && toRecipients.length() > 0) {
                String[] to = new String[toRecipients.length()];
                for (int i=0; i<toRecipients.length(); i++) {
                    to[i] = toRecipients.getString(i);
                }
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling toRecipients param: " + e.toString());
        }

        // setting CC recipients
        try {
            JSONArray ccRecipients = parameters.getJSONArray("ccRecipients");
            if (ccRecipients != null && ccRecipients.length() > 0) {
                String[] cc = new String[ccRecipients.length()];
                for (int i=0; i<ccRecipients.length(); i++) {
                    cc[i] = ccRecipients.getString(i);
                }
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling ccRecipients param: " + e.toString());
        }

        // setting BCC recipients
        try {
            JSONArray bccRecipients = parameters.getJSONArray("bccRecipients");
            if (bccRecipients != null && bccRecipients.length() > 0) {
                String[] bcc = new String[bccRecipients.length()];
                for (int i=0; i<bccRecipients.length(); i++) {
                    bcc[i] = bccRecipients.getString(i);
                }
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, bcc);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling bccRecipients param: " + e.toString());
        }

        // setting attachments
        try {
            JSONArray attachments = parameters.getJSONArray("attachments");
            if (attachments != null && attachments.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
                for (int i=0; i<attachments.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        File file = new File(attachments.getString(i));
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                            uris.add(uri);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error adding an attachment: " + e.toString());
                    }
                }
                if (uris.size() > 0) {
                    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.e("EmailComposer", "Error handling attachments param: " + e.toString());
        }

        this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, emailIntent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        // TODO handle callback
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        LOG.e("EmailComposer", "ResultCode: " + resultCode);
        // IT DOESN'T SEEM TO HANDLE RESULT CODES
    }

}
```

**emailcomposer.js**

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/emailcomposer", function(require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require('cordova/exec');

    var EmailComposer = function() {
        this.resultCallback = null; // Function
    };

    EmailComposer.ComposeResultType = {
        Cancelled:0,
        Saved:1,
        Sent:2,
        Failed:3,
        NotSent:4
    }


    // showEmailComposer : all args optional
    EmailComposer.prototype.showEmailComposer = function(successCallback,failureCallback,subject,body,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients,bIsHTML,attachments) {
    console.log("showEmailComposer()");
    var args = {};
    if(toRecipients)
        args.toRecipients = toRecipients;
    if(ccRecipients)
        args.ccRecipients = ccRecipients;
    if(bccRecipients)
        args.bccRecipients = bccRecipients;
    if(subject)
        args.subject = subject;
    if(body)
        args.body = body;
    if(bIsHTML)
        args.bIsHTML = bIsHTML;
    if(attachments)
        args.attachments = attachments;

    cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
}


    var emailcomposer = new EmailComposer();
    module.exports = emailcomposer;
});
```

Change line in config.xml to:

```
<plugin name="EmailComposer" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.EmailComposer"/>
```

Then something like this for index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.8.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="emailcomposer.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function deviceready() {
            console.log("Device ready");            
        }

        function composeHTML(){
            cordova.require('cordova/plugin/emailcomposer').showEmailComposer(
                function() { console.log( 'successfully called email composer' ); },
                function() { console.log( 'failed to call email composer' ); },
                "Look at this photo",
                "Take a look at <b>this<b/>:",
                ["fred@blogs.com", "peter@pan.com"],
                [],
                [],
                true,
                ["image.jpg", "file.zip"]
            );
        }

        function composeText(){
            cordova.require('cordova/plugin/emailcomposer').showEmailComposer(
                function() { console.log( 'successfully called email composer' ); },
                function() { console.log( 'failed to call email composer' ); },
                "Look at this photo",
                "Take a look at this:",
                ["fred@blogs.com", "peter@pan.com"],
                [],
                [],
                false,
                ["image.jpg", "file.zip"]
            );
        }
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, true);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>EmailComposer</h1>
        <button onclick="composeText();">Compose Text Email</button>
        <button onclick="composeHTML();">Compose HTML Email</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks bro.Do you have any idea of socket programming, i need web socket plugin for android and Ios. Actually i search a lot but getting old plugin .Do you have any latest plugin of web socket .

Comment: My second question is that is there any use of cordovawebclient.java file and webclient ? what is use of these .may be i can use in my other project .?.But i need some help in socket programming.

Comment: I added you code in my project .I am getting " successfully called email composer at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:135"But along with i am getting ResultCode=0.When i check on emulator i am not seen any thing..:(

Comment: But when i check on android device . i am able to see some thing like Header (complete action using )Bluetooth, Gmail,message.i am not able to see Email like stucture.

Comment: If you get any future help other.I know you are professional.I am trying my best to do same task.if you get any time make plugin for other.actually i am from poor family sorry

Comment: Hi, i am using your provided code. It doesn't attach file neither it sets body text any solution for this.

Comment: @sur007: As I mentioned in my answer, I couldn't get this to work with the stock Email app, only with the Gmail app. That was sufficient for my needs so I didn't take it further.

Comment: @Dpac99c, i too need it for gmail. With me even with gmail is not working.

Comment: Possible that updates to Gmail app have broken it then, as it worked back in June when I tested it with Phonegap 2.5.0.

Comment: Thanks for this!  After spending hours messing with the plugin as it is on GitHub, your source finally got it working.  you should submit a pull request.  I'm using Cordova 2.7.0.